# SQL Server ASP.Net App can't connect

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am having a spot of trouble connecting to SQL Server via an ASP.Net application. I have used this before on SQL Server 2008/2012 and didn't have any issues with it. But in 2016, I can't seem to find the culprite. I have Googled extensivley without any luck. I will try and list all the things I've already tried with no luck.

It's running via IIS on my PC

- Firewall is off
- TCP/IP is enabled
- Tried network service and created a user with login on SQL Server
- Can connect in Visual Studio and created DBML file which has all tables and correct connection string
- Tried Integrated security connection string and connection string with user login details

Im sure the are other things I have tried also but as I've tried so much I cna't remeber what else. I have attached a screen shot of the problem, any suggestions would be great.

[image]

Comment: The error tells you... You should check that the application user account has write permission to the file path of AppData folder

Comment: The error pages explains everything - why the error occured, how to fix it and why the *server version* is irrelevant. If you want to use user-instance databases, you have to be able to write to the target folder no matter the version. Have you tried the instructions of the error message?

Comment: This question should be closed as a duplicate of itself - it already contains a very good answer

Comment: Are you sure the same connection string being used at runtime? Did you debug the code check if the connection string being used is correct?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya check the screenshot. It explains exactly what's wrong and how to fix it

Comment: Treid what it suggests no luck

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya connections strings are correct.

Comment: connection string in `web.config` is not correct. Please show your connection  and the sql server name

Comment: <add name="DevSiteConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=IT-DEPT;Initial Catalog=DevSite;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: SQL Server Name is IT-DEPT, Database is DevSite, also tried connection string with SQL Login details which are dbowner etc of the database

Answer (score 0):

Open "Sql Server Configuration Manager". Click on "SQL Server Services" in the left hand column, this will open a panel on the right hand side.

Ensure that the following services running:

- SQL Server
- SQL Server Browser

Comment: Have already checked and restarted services after any other change I have made to ensure it is up to date.